# Modify the lattice path for Catalan Number

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

It is known that $C_{n}$ ($n$-th Catalan number) is the number of monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with $n\times n$ square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal. A monotonic path is one which starts in the lower left corner, finishes in the upper right corner, and consists entirely of edges pointing rightwards or upwards.

> - Let $n=14$ and $a_{1}\leq a_{2}\leq a_{3}\leq a_{4}$.  I want to pass the following points:

$$(4,a_{1}), (8,a_{2}), (11,a_{3}),(13,a_{4})$$ such that $a_{1}<4,a_{2}<8, a_{3}<11, a_{4}<13$. Now,
What is the number of monotonic lattice paths  along the edges of a grid with $n\times n$ square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal.

It seems that we use Catalan's triangle. However, I fail to do so. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle

Comment: What is actually your question?

Comment: You either need to explain more clearly, or include a nontrivial, illustrated example, because I also cannot tell what you mean by saying $(0,0)\to (x_1,a_2)\to (x_2,a_2)\dots$. For example, when $n=4$, $k=2$, $a_1=2$, $a_2=3$, can you give us the complete list of paths which fit your description?

Comment: If this is a step by step path, there's a problem with $(x_1, a_1)$ given the constraints.  You state $1 \le a_1$ but also want $a_1 < x_1$, which seems to say that the step after $(0,0)$ is at least $(2,1)$ which is usually considered the result of 3 steps.

Comment: Maybe I'm not making myself clear. I  edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem decomposes into five separate problems. You need to find the number of paths from $(0,0)\to (4,a_1)$ which do not go above $y=x$, then the number of paths $(4,a_1)\to (8,a_2)$ which do not go above $y=x$, and so on up to $(13,a_4)\to (14,14)$. You then multiply those five numbers together.

Each sub-problem is answered by the following proposition:

> Given integer points $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$, both at or below the line $y=x$, such that you can get from $P_1$ to $P_2$ by moving right and up alone, the number of paths from $P_1$ to $P_2$ which do not go above $y=x$ is$$
> \binom{(x_2-x_1)+(y_2-y_1)}{x_2-x_1}-
> \binom{(x_2-x_1)+(y_2-y_1)}{y_2-1-x_1}.
> $$

This can be proved using the reflection principle. If you take a "bad" path from $P_1$ to $P_2$ which at some point hits the line $y=x+1$, and reflect the subsequent portion of the path through $y=x+1$ after it first hits that line, then you get an arbitrary path from $P_1$ to $P_3:=(y_2-1,x_2+1)$. This process is reversible, so the number of "bad" paths is simply the total number of paths from $P_1$ to $P_3$. Therefore, the number of "good" paths is given by the subtraction displayed above.